# How can one recover SSO from a disaster?

Tags: biztalk

I am trying to test recovery from a disaster, but feel the SSO part is like a Catch 22 situation. I cannot get it to work.

We have a DB cluster where SSO is also a clustered service, just like the documentation recommends.

I want to be able to recover from a DB/SSO cluster disaster. So the we have a third DB server for log shipping. On that server we also have a “waiting” SSO service to take over as Master. That SSO has joined the current one, but is not Master.

The problem is to make that server the backup server SSO Master.

We cannot run `ssomanage -updatedb NewServer.xml` if the old DB is down. We cannot `ssoconfig -restoresecret secret.bak`, since it is not the Master.

Has anyone done this and got it to work?

Comment: Not exactly your case here, but it might shed some light on things for DR; http://fehlberg.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/biztalk-disaster-recovery-planning/

Comment: +1 for actually testing disaster recovery plans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved.

One have to point SSO to the new DB before starting the service.

These are the steps to move a SSO master to another server.

Run on the new server:

1. `ssomanage -serverall <New SSO SERVER NAME>`
2. I used SSO Administration GUI to set new DB, but recording to MS you can use `ssoconfig -setdb <New DB SERVER NAME> <DATABASE NAME>`
3. `ssomanage -updatedb NewServer.xml`
4. Start SSO service
5. `ssoconfig -restoresecret <backup file path>`

Voila! Now this SSO is the master.